# Installing Xcode fixes most python missing library issues?

Tags: python, xcode

I really need pycurl on my mac.

I am having a lot of trouble running python code on my Mac mainly because I have barely any libraries to work with. For example, if I type

```
import pycurl
```

Gives me the error:

> ImportError: No module named pycurl

Okay cool, so lets install pycurl then with pycurl-7.19.3:

```
Matts-MacBook-Pro:pycurl-7.19.3 CiniCraft$ python setup.py install
Using curl-config (libcurl 7.21.4)
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 487, in <module>
    setup(**setup_args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 563, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 127, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 307, in run
    customize_compiler(self.compiler)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/sysconfig.py", line 170, in customize_compiler
    _osx_support.customize_compiler(_config_vars)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_osx_support.py", line 418, in customize_compiler
    _find_appropriate_compiler(_config_vars)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_osx_support.py", line 191, in _find_appropriate_compiler
    "Cannot locate working compiler")
SystemError: Cannot locate working compiler
```

Of course, that doesn't work either so lets easy_install it:

```
sudo easy_install pycurl


Searching for pycurl
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/
Best match: pycurl 7.19.3
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.19.3.tar.gz#md5=b9091b7438d3de1552e28862d2971cd1
Processing pycurl-7.19.3.tar.gz
Running pycurl-7.19.3/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-d16j45/pycurl-7.19.3/egg-dist-tmp-6PRcV6
Using curl-config (libcurl 7.21.4)
unable to execute llvm-gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'llvm-gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

I think at this point I've tried everything... I'm downloading an old copy of Xcode 4.2.1 for OS X 10.7.3

Is it true that Xcode should add all the python libraries that I need and hopefully solve most of my problems?

Comment: How are we supposed to know which libraries you need and what your problems are?

Comment: ah sorry about that, for now I really need pycurl

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the latest version of XCode from the App Store
2. From XCode, go to Preferences -> Downloads -> Components
3. download the Command Line Tools

and then go ahead and install pycurl